# Jersey+Spring - Injecting servlet request

Tags: java, spring, jersey, grizzly

I'm starting a Grizzly server as follows:

```
URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(9998).build();

ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
resourceConfig.packages("com.example");
resourceConfig.property("contextConfig", applicationContext);

HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, resourceConfig, false);

server.start();
```

In the package **com.example**, I have filters as follows:

```
@Component
@Provider
@Priority(0)
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        /* httpServletRequest is null here */
    }
}
```

My filter is instantiated as expected by Spring. Also, JAX-RS detected it and uses the same instance instantiated by Spring. I'm trying to access the underlying `HttpServletRequest` but I can't find how.

I'm aware that the servlet request will never be injected until the filter instance is created as a proxy since the servlet request is request scoped. I tried to annotate the filter with `@RequestScope`, same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [GrizzlyWebContainerFactory](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/index.html?org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/servlet/GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.html) from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

if you want to create servlet container. Currently, you are not creating a servlet container, that's why there is no `HttpServletRequest` available.

You can do something like

```
GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(baseUri, new ServletContainer(resourceConfig));
```

Comment: Is it possible not to use a servlet container? When using a servlet based deployment, the Spring component provider expects a WebApplicationContext while my context is standalone AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.

Comment: When my application starts, the root application context is created based on a Spring Configuration class. I want this root context to be available to Jersey therefore I was setting the contextConfig property. However, this property is irrelevant when servlet container is used and in such case a WebApplicationContext is expected under servlet attribute 
org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT.

Comment: Not really, as it's a servlet API. What are you trying to access? You can inject the Grizzly `Request` with `@Context`. Maybe that will give you enough information.

Comment: Trying to access httpServletRequest.getLocalAddr(), httpServletRequest.getLocalPort(), httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr(), httpServletRequest.getRemotePort()

Comment: I think you can get that stuff from the Grizzly `Request`

Comment: I tried not using servlet container (initial config in question), and injecting Grizzly Request instead of HttpServletRequest. I get the following error during startup:WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.

Comment: Odd. I'm sure it's proxied. What happens if you remove the `@Component` on the filter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132288/discussion-between-mickael-marrache-and-peeskillet).

Comment: So you just need to inject it with `Provider` like `private javax.inject.Provider<Request> requestProvider`. Then call `requestProvider.get()` to get the `Request`

Comment: The `Provider` allows it to be lazily retrieved, as I guess it is not proxied like I thought